# Exporting html table to excel from Javascript in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have the following code from button click event in client side. It is opening the excel in Chrome. However, in IE, it is just appending to the URL and it is not working as desired.

```
function generateexcel() {

    var table = document.getElementById("tsttable");

    var c = table.innerHTML;

    var html = c.trim()

    //add more symbols if needed...
    while (html.indexOf('á') != -1) html = html.replace('á', '&aacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('é') != -1) html = html.replace('é', '&eacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('í') != -1) html = html.replace('í', '&iacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('ó') != -1) html = html.replace('ó', '&oacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('ú') != -1) html = html.replace('ú', '&uacute;');
    while (html.indexOf('º') != -1) html = html.replace('º', '&ordm;');

    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(html));
}
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/datauri

Comment: So is there any other way in client side or i have to move to server side solution?

Comment: I believe you should do that server-side, but maybe there is a way... Let's see if someone answers.

Comment: IE hates data URIs. Good luck.

Comment: Figured out myself through javascript

Comment: function TableToExcel(tableid) {

                var id = $('[id$="' + tableid + '"]');
                var strCopy = $('<div></div>').html(id.clone()).html();
                window.clipboardData.setData("Text", strCopy);
                var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                objExcel.visible = false;

                var objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add;
                var objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1);
                objWorksheet.Paste;
                objExcel.visible = true;


            }

Comment: Since you're probably just doing an HTML table anyway, why don't you just open the URL with a table on it in Excel?  It's pretty good at loading tables from a normal web page.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your table to xml or csv in IE. So your user can open it with excel. Good Luck.