# Any way to export either excel or csv file from Javascript in IE9 or Higher

Tags: javascript, excel, csv

I've researched this for a couple of days now, and come across [this one](https://gist.github.com/insin/1031969) which works fine for Chrome and Firefox, but not IE.  I've come across [this one from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634632/exporting-html-table-to-excel-from-javascript-in-internet-explorer) that is supposedly IE friendly, but chokes on `var objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");`.  I've tried xlsx.js, but can't use flash.

I've researched CSV, but come accross similar issues with URI's in IE causing chokes.

I'm trying to keep it client side ( as I've already got the data stored locally ), but I have to have IE 9+ available ( as my primary users will be using IE9 [not by my choice]).

Any solutions, or am I stuck going server-side for this?

Comment: How would you know if user has Excel installed? If this is an intranet app, you could ask users to set some permittions in IE to allow execute ActiveX at Intranet Zone.

Comment: I know that all users using this would have Excel - so I'm not worried about checking for Excel.  Plus its just downloading an excel file that they could save if they didn't have it.

Comment: If your users trust you, you can ask them to add your page to Trusted page list, though I wouldn't allow any web page to execute ActiveX in my machine... Why don't you just save the file to a server, users can download it when needed...

Comment: If that's the way I need to go, then that's what I'll do - but if I could do it client side with Javascript, that would have been much sweeter and nicer...  Plus would have saved me an API call.

Comment: Also - I've tested this on my machine with IE11, set to be completely open for ActiveX ( since I don't use IE on my machine for anything other than testing web pages I build ), and it still choked on the `ActiveXObject` call.

Comment: If _all_ (13) rights are allowed, the problem is usually unregistered ActiveX, or your anti-virus software is blocking the script? The error message is "Automation Server can't create object ."?

Comment: Yes - that is the message I get!

Comment: Just make a search at SO using the error message as keywords, there's a lot of questions about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have access to IE9.  Does this solution work for you?  http://bl.ocks.org/insin/1031969

How about setting a `data:` url, like this:

```
window.location.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,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';
```

If that doesn't work, then I think you have two options:

- Use a server-side component to prepare the download.  This can be a very simple component that just returns a GET parameter as a file.
- Display a page to the user that contains the data, and have them copy it into Excel.  You could use tab-delimited text, or an HTML table - either one of those should paste nicely into a spreadsheet.

Comment: This is the first one I referenced - just that I used the github version vs. his blog...  Unfortunately IE9+ chokes on the `window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))` portion...

Comment: IE does not allow use of `data:` URI for "downloading" files.